# How to update a class attribute when an instance attribute changes?

Tags: python, class, instance-variables, class-attributes, renewal

I am working on optimization problems. As you know, optimization is an iterative process. Some sections are selected, and the weight of all sections is calculated.

I have code like this:

```
class Test:
    W = 0

    def __init__(self, l, A):
        self.l = l
        self.A = A
        Test.W += self.A * self.l

instance1 = Test(5, 10)
instance2 = Test(3, 7)
instance3 = Test(6, 13)

print(Test.W)

instance1.A = 20
instance2.A = 30
instance3.A = 40

print(Test.W)
```

At creation of instances 1-3, the program calculated 149 for `W`. It is correct.
But if I change `A` values, the result is 149 again and again.

How can I update the class attribute `W` when I change `A` or `l`?

Comment: The ``__init__`` code is not going to get rerun just because you changed an instance attribute.  If you want to have side effects from setting an instance parameter, you should implement a `Test.setA(new_A)` method.

Comment: Consider, without the added complexity of classes, if I have the statements `a = 1`, `x = a`, `a = 3`, then `print(x)` will print `1` not `3`.  Assignment statements don't set up some on-going variable relationship.  They get evaluated only when they are executed, and the `Test.__init__()` code only gets executed when the instances are being initialized.

Comment: This really shouldn't be a class attribute - that kind of design has a lot of awkward consequences if you want to solve *two* optimization problems, or if you want to write unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want modifications made to an instance attribute to effect the value of a class attribute, you can make the instance attribute a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) and place the additional logics in its setter method instead:

```
class Test:
    W = 0

    def __init__(self, l, A):
        self.l = l
        self.A = A

    @property
    def A(self):
        try:
            return self._A
        except AttributeError:
            return 0

    @A.setter
    def A(self, value):
        Test.W += (value - self.A) * self.l
        self._A = value
```

so that:

```
instance1 = Test(5, 10)
instance2 = Test(3, 7)
instance3 = Test(6, 13)

print(Test.W)

instance1.A = 20
instance2.A = 30
instance3.A = 40

print(Test.W)
```

outputs:

```
149
430
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/pqUN4w

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the fact that the class attribute W is calculated only once during the instantiation of the class. If you want to update the class attribute W when you change the values of A or l for an instance, you can create a method to recalculate and update W. You can use a class method for this purpose.

```
    class Test:
    W = 0

    def __init__(self, l, A):
        self.l = l
        self.A = A
        Test.calculate_and_update_W(self)

    @classmethod
    def calculate_and_update_W(cls, instance):
        cls.W += instance.A * instance.l

# Create instances
instance1 = Test(5, 10)
instance2 = Test(3, 7)
instance3 = Test(6, 13)

# Print initial value of Test.W
print(Test.W)

# Update A values for instances
instance1.A = 20
instance2.A = 30
instance3.A = 40

# Recalculate and update Test.W
Test.calculate_and_update_W(instance1)
Test.calculate_and_update_W(instance2)
Test.calculate_and_update_W(instance3)

# Print updated value of Test.W
print(Test.W)
```

In this version, I added a calculate_and_update_W class method, which takes an instance of the class as an argument and recalculates and updates the class attribute W accordingly. This method is then called during the initialization (**init**) to set the initial value and can be called again whenever you want to update W based on the current values of A and l.